# undoing interrupted 'mv' (move) command

Tags: linux, shell, mv

I hope this is the right place to ask this question.

While trying to move a big directory "`mydirname`" (abt900GB), in a remote linux server, from `/abc/source` to `/xyz/target` ; I used the following command in `source`directory,

```
mv mydirname /xyz/target/ &
```

However, after a while the process got interrupted  and gave an error,

```
mv: cannot stat `mydirname/GS9/set04/trans/run.3/acc': Stale file handle
mv: cannot stat `mydirname/GS9/set04/trans/run.4/amc': Stale file handle
.
.
.
and many more such messages mentioning different subdirectories locations.
```

The problem is that, the process has moved about 300gb of data. However, there are many directories which are not fully moved. Similar, problem occurred with another transfer (about 500 GB) that was running at the same machine.

Also, I am no longer in the same working session. I have disconnected and reconnected to the remote server.

It would be great if you help with following queries.

1. Is it possible that some of the file are not fully-transferred (i have seen such cases in 'cp' command where if a process interrupts, it results in lesser size file at the destination.
2. How can I resume the process so that I do not loose any data. Will 'mv' command be enough? or is there any special command that can work in background.
3. Else, is there a command to undo the process and restore the '`mydirname`' to original location '`source`'.

Comment: Are source and target on the same volume?

Comment: Using something like screen (or one of it's alternatives) is used for long-running processes to prevent dependency on connection.

Comment: I am not sure, i'll have to ask from the IT-admin. However, when i do 'cd /' i can see both  '/abc' and '/xyz' using 'ls'

Comment: Are they under the same mount points, the command "df /abc /xyz" will show that. If they are, your "mv" is actually copy & delete.

Comment: I am aware of 'screen' command; however, one of my friend told me that i can use '&' and it also perform 'similar' function of running job in background.

Comment: When `mv` moves between filesystems, it should copy first, than remove old file. So if it interrupted, you should get incomplete files in destination directory and full files in source dir. I suggest you checking sizes with `find -ls`. Also, do not use `mv` in such cases, `cpio -pvmd` or `rsync` is better.

Comment: Use rsync and delete the source after the transfer completes sucessfully. Rsync will fix partially copied files by transferring only the difference. If your source and destination are on different volumes, `mv`ing is pretty much just copying followed by deletion of the source.

Comment: @  Roman Susi : i think not !  it shows following details : [link] http://tinypic.com/r/5ygh04/8 

ps: i have change the directory name as per the question.

Answer (score 4):

Use "rsync" to complete a job like this:

```
rsync -av --delete mydirname/ /xyz/target
```

It will verify that all files are moved, of the proper length, correct timestamps and will delete any leftover garbage.

You can test first with a "dry run" to see what the damages are:

```
rsync -avn --delete mydirname/ /xyz/target
```

This goes through the whole rsync process but doesn't actually do anything. It's usually a good idea to run this test to check your command syntax and see if it's going to do what you think it should do.

The "rsync" command is actually more like a copy "cp" than a move "mv". It will leave the source files in place and you can delete them later when you are satisfied that everthing has transferred correctly.

Comment: Initially i used, "mv mydirname xyz/target/". Is "rsync -avn mydirname /xyz/target/" and "rsync -avn mydirname/ /xyz/target/" same?   On running  "rsync -avn mydirname /xyz/target/" i got following message:
sent 198913 bytes  received 26613 bytes  16705.63 bytes/sec
total size is 845407797509  speedup is 3748604.58 (DRY RUN).

Comment: With rsync the use or non-use of the trailing slash "/" is critical and must be handled correctly. You did not follow my example exactly in any of your tests. This is completely non-intuitive and took me some time to get right. There should be a trailing slash on the first argument and none on the second. That will pick up all the files in "mydirname" and place them under "target".

Comment: Thankyou Hankster! I understand the importance of '/', that is why I insisted on it. To make my question clearer: because I used 'mv' command earlier, the target folder '/xyz/target' already have (part of) the  source folder 'mydirname' and its subdirectories. So, would you advice me to use 1. "rsync -avn mydirname/ /xyz/target" or,2. "rsync -avn mydirname/ /xyz/target/mydirname" or,3. "rsync -avn mydirname /xyz/target/mydirname" or,4. "rsync -avn mydirname/ /xyz/target/mydirname/" or anything else?

Comment: Sorry but I might have been too hasty. I think "mv mydirname /xyz/target/" would have the rsync equivalent of "rsync -av mydirname /xyz/target"

Comment: And perhaps consider using rsync as a replacement for mv in the first place?  This way, you can simply repeat the same command if it's interrupted...  without having to remember in a panic whether the source or target need trailing slashes :-P